# create a team rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

A user belongs_to a team a team has_many users. A user can only belong to one team at a time. I want a user to be able to create a team, join an existing team, or leave their current team. Below is what I have in the models, controllers, and views right now, but it is not working.

Also, I want the person who creates the team to be the team leader (administrator). Can someone please tell me how to do this?

User Model:

```
belongs_to :team, dependent: :destroy


def team_member?
 team.present?
end

def join!(team)
 team.create!
end  

def unjoin!(team)
 team.destroy
end
```

team model:

```
 has_many :users

 attr_accessible :team_name, :team_id

 validates :team_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }

 default_scope order: 'teams.created_at DESC'
```

team controller:

```
before_filter :signed_in_user

def join
  @team = Team.find params[:id]
  current_user.update_attribute(:team_id, @team.id)
  redirect_to @team
end

def leave
  @team = Team.find params[:id]
  current_user.update_attribute(:team_id, nil)
  redirect_to @team
end

  def create
    @team = Team.new(params[:team])
    if @team.save
      flash[:success] = "Team Created!"  
      redirect_to @team
    else
     render 'new'
    end
  end
```

_join_team_.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.team.join) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :team_name %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Join", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Associations seems to be fine. Work on code. To add "teamlead" you can add `has_one` association to team model:

```
has_one :teamlead, :class => "User", :dependent => :nullify
```